# unit test If statement angular6

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a simple if statement in angular6, for which I need to write unit test

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.actionResult){
      this.dataTable = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.actionResult));
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataTable);
      this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();
    }        
  }
```

The code-coverage shows that`if path not taken`, how can I cover this in my spec.ts.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Also have some assertions like

- `dataTable` toBeTruthy()/toBeDefined()
- Similarly for `dataSource`.
- `spy` on the method `_updateChangeSubscription` and expect it to have been called

This assertions will make your code full proof.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418086/jest-expected-mock-function-to-have-been-called-but-it-was-not-called/54763110#54763110) to some other question for reference.